# Mapping from array of dictionaries to array of numbers in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, mapping, nsarray, swift4

Here is a function that should turn an an array of key-value pairs for orders `NSArray` containing `Dictionary<String, Any>` to an array of IDs for each order (`[NSNumber]`).

However, I am still having problem with the type conversion, the error:

> Type 'Any' has no subscript members

How to perform the mapping cleanly in Swift?

```
@objc static func ordersLoaded(notification:Notification) -> [NSNumber] {   

    // Function receives a Notification object from Objective C     
    let userInfo:Dictionary = notification.userInfo as! Dictionary<String, Any>

    // orders is an array of key-value pairs for each order Dictionary<String,Any>
    let ordersWithKeyValuePairs:NSArray = userInfo["orders"] as! NSArray // Here a typed array of Dictionaries would be preferred

    // it needs to be simplified to an array of IDs for each order (NSNumber)
    // orderID is one of the keys
    let orderIDs:[NSNumber];
    orderIDs = ordersWithKeyValuePairs.flatMap({$0["orderID"] as? NSNumber}) // Line with the error
    /*
    orderIDs = ordersWithKeyValuePairs.map({
        (key,value) in
        if key==["orderID"] {
            return value
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }) as! [NSNumber]
    */

    return orderIDs
}
```

Comment: NSArray is defined like `[Any]`, so thats why you get the issue. Don't use NS classes in Swift unless you really have to. In this case, cast to the expected type, maybe: `[AnyHashable: Any]`

Comment: Still getting the error `Type 'AnyHashable' has no subscript members` when doing `orderIDs = ordersWithKeyValuePairs.flatMap({$0["orderID"] as? NSNumber})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what worked, casting `ordersWithKeyValuePairs` to `[Dictionary<String, Any>]` solved the problem to me:

```
@objc static func ordersLoaded(notification:Notification) -> [NSNumber] {   

    // Function receives a Notification object from Objective C     
    let userInfo:Dictionary = notification.userInfo as! Dictionary<String, Any>

    // orders is an array of key-value pairs for each order Dictionary<String,Any>
    let ordersWithKeyValuePairs:[Dictionary<String, Any>] = userInfo["orders"] as! [Dictionary<String, Any>]
    // it needs to be simplified to an array of IDs for each order (NSNumber)
    // orderID is one of the keys
    let orderIDs:[NSNumber];
    orderIDs = ordersWithKeyValuePairs.flatMap({$0["orderID"] as? NSNumber}) // Line with the error

    return orderIDs
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try this

```
if let ordersWithKeyValuePairs = userInfo["orders"] as? [[String:Any]] {

   let result = ordersWithKeyValuePairs.compactMap{$0["orderID"] as? Int }
}
```